# Pointer array *grades[]

Tags: c++, arrays

I mange to insert two differnt arrays addresses into pointer array but when I print it, it only gives me the first arrary. and not both of them:

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int *readGrades(int *grades[], int size);

#define SIZE 2

void main()
{
    int *grades[SIZE], *length,x;
    length=readGrades(grades, SIZE);

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        x = *(length+i);
        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
            cout << *(grades[i] + j) << endl;
    }
}

int *readGrades(int *grades[], int size)
{
    int num_grades, count[SIZE],j,x;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << "How many grades for student " <<i+1<< "?" << endl;
        cin >> num_grades;
        cout << "Insert " << num_grades << " grades\n";

        grades[i] = new int[num_grades];
        for ( j = 0; j < num_grades; j++)
        {
            cin >> *(grades[i] + j);
            x = *(grades[i] + j);
        }
        count[i] = j;
    }
    return count;
}
```

how can i print both of the arrays?

Comment: have you checked for values of x in for loop of main?

Answer (score 3):

You return an `int*` `count` in `readGrades`, by the time `length` is assigned `count` is already destroyed and you have a dangling pointer which leads to undefined behaviour upon dereferencing. Stop using pointers all together and use `std::vector`.

Comment: but you helped me alot. I made it!

Comment: @pkz: Write a very simplified vector *equivalent* as [Demo](http://ideone.com/87IrZW)